# Passing Data Through Intents & A single AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I have multiple buttons, and each, when clicked, load the same class. In this class, I have an AsyncTask, and I also have two buttons. One is to install the theme. Basically, all I need to do when you click install is to download a file. The thing is, I need to download the file corresponding to the button I pressed in the first class. Basically, I need an if statement, and saying if button x is pressed, download this file, but if button y is pressed, download this other file. I attempted to do it myself, but failed. Below is my classes. I basically need help downloading the file corresponding to the button that was pressed...

BootFragment.java:

```
 package com.cydeon.plasmamodz;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

 import com.stericson.RootTools.RootTools;
 import com.stericson.RootTools.exceptions.RootDeniedException;
 import com.stericson.RootTools.execution.CommandCapture;

 import android.app.Fragment;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Environment;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.Button;

      public class BootFragment extends Fragment {{


    //Defining File Directory
    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/plasma/boot");
    if(directory.exists() && directory.isDirectory()){
    //Do nothing. Directory is existent 
    }else{
    //Directory does not exist. Make directory (First time app users)
    directory.mkdirs();
    }

    File bkup = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/plasma/boot/bkup");
    if(bkup.exists() && bkup.isDirectory()){
    //Do nothing. Directory is existent 
    }else{
    //Directory does not exist. Make directory (First time app users)
    bkup.mkdirs();
    }}





@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.boot_frag,
                container, false);
     Button Ablue = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bABlue);
     Button AblueR = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bABlueR);
     Button Abokeh = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bAbokeh);

     Ablue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent b = new Intent(getActivity(), Boots.class);
                    b.putExtra("Dragon", R.id.bABlue);
                    BootFragment.this.startActivity(b);
            }
            });

     AblueR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent c = new Intent(getActivity(), Boots.class);
                        c.putExtra("Xbox", R.id.bABlueR);
                        BootFragment.this.startActivity(c);
                }
                });

     Abokeh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent d = new Intent(getActivity(), Boots.class);
                        d.putExtra("GameB", R.id.bAbokeh);
                        BootFragment.this.startActivity(d);
                }
                });

     return view;



   }}
```

Boots.java:

```
    package com.cydeon.plasmamodz;

import com.stericson.RootTools.*;
import com.stericson.RootTools.exceptions.RootDeniedException;
import com.stericson.RootTools.execution.CommandCapture;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import com.cydeon.plasmamodz.R;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

//Class for Boot Animation Blue Kindle
public class Boots extends Activity {

public static String TAG = "Boots";
Process process;

private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sURL) {
        try{
            URL url = new URL(sURL[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            //Shows 0-100% progress bar
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            //Download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/plasma/boot/b..ootanimation.zip");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                //Publish the Progress
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100/fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Installing. Please Wait";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

        if (RootTools.isBusyboxAvailable()){
            RootTools.remount("/system", "rw");
            CommandCapture command = new CommandCapture(0, "su", "sh /sdcard/plasma/scripts/boots.sh");
                try {
                    RootTools.getShell(true).add(command).waitForFinish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (RootDeniedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        } else {
            RootTools.offerBusyBox(Boots.this);
        }

    }
}

ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.boots);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.boot1);
    Button install = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAInstall);
    Button rtrn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAReturn);
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Boots.this);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading..." );
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

    install.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            TextView creator = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCreate);
            Intent bootI = getIntent();
            int dball = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Dragon", -1);
            int xbox = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Xbox", -1);
            int GameB = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("GameB", 1);
            if (dball != -1){
            DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
            downloadFile.execute("http:\\correspondingurl");
            creator.setText("Dragon Ball");
            }if (xbox != -1){
                DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
                downloadFile.execute("http:\\correspondingurl");
                creator.setText("Xbox");
            }if (GameB != -1){
                DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
                downloadFile.execute("http:\\correspondingurl");
                creator.setText("GameBoy");
            }


            }

        }
    );

    rtrn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    }



}
```

Comment: *I attempted to do it myself, but failed* :- what issue u are getting with current code ?

Comment: It downloads the GameB url and displays the GameBoy textView. For all three buttons.

Comment: why u are sending three strings because you can minimize code by sending only one string value like : `b.putExtra("Download_Type","Dragon");` ?

Comment: for all ur buttons you can use setTag and getTag to identify ur buttons or you can also identify by their id....http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/10586 here is some sample code....

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getIntExtra()` instead of `getInt()` in these statements:

```
        int dball = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Dragon", -1);
        int xbox = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Xbox", -1);
        int GameB = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("GameB", 1);
```

Comment: 'Extra' not 'Extr'. You're missing an 'a'.

Comment: I misspelled it when typing the comment. It is 'Extra' in my app.

Comment: are you getting the values for the variables? or are they always -1?